# How to save images while using Orweb?

Tags: orbot

So I have a Xperia Live and I'm using Orbot-Orweb.And I want to save images (from Google,DA,etcetera) How can I do it?Normally all I have to do is long click on an image.Now what?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible in Orweb. It is a very basic browse that lacks features like saving images.

If you want to be able to do this there are two possibilities:

1. Use Firefox Mobile and configure it using our [Privacy Enhanced](https://guardianproject.info/apps/firefoxprivacy/) instructions.
2. Try the development builds of our new Firefox-based secure browser, named [Orfox](https://guardianproject.info/builds/Orfox/latest/).

   *This is development/debug grade technology and has not been fully tested!* **Do not use for strong anonymity or security**

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't working now you might be able to just take a screen shot using your phone as a workaround, having a similar effect, even if using Orfox of course is the better way.